# Scala type inference: can't infer IndexedSeq[T] from Array[T]

Tags: arrays, scala, implicit-conversion, type-inference, scala-collections

In Scala 2.11.2, the following minimal example compiles only when using **type ascription** on the `Array[String]`:

```
object Foo {    

  def fromList(list: List[String]): Foo = new Foo(list.toArray : Array[String])   

}

class Foo(source: IndexedSeq[String])
```

If I remove the type ascription in `fromList`, it will fail to compile with the following error:

```
Error:(48, 56) polymorphic expression cannot be instantiated to expected type;
 found   : [B >: String]Array[B]
 required: IndexedSeq[String]
  def fromList(list: List[String]): Foo = new Foo(list.toArray)
                                                       ^
```

Why can't the compiler infer the `Array[String]` here? Or does this issue have to do something with the implicit conversion from `Array`'s to `IndexedSeq`'s?

Comment: Note I think you can do: `object Foo { def fromList(list: List[String]): Foo = new Foo(list.toArray[String])}` instead.

Comment: Or just `list.toIndexedSeq`, of course. The question's still a good one, though.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. The reason I'm going for `Array`s instead of `IndexedSeq`s is purely for performance reasons. I had to profile the function and found that `Vector`s take more overhead when creating lots of small instances.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that the `.toArray` method returns an Array of some type `B` which is a superclass of the `T` in `List[T]`. This allows you to use a `list.toArray` on `List[Bar]` where an `Array[Foo]` is required if `Bar` extends `Foo`.

Yes, the real reason this doesn't work out of the box is that the compiler is trying to figure out which `B` to use and also how to get to an `IndexedSeq`. It seems like it's trying to resolve the `IndexedSeq[String]` requirement but `B` is only guaranteed to be a `String` or a superclass of `String`; hence the error.

This is my preferred work around:

```
def fromList(list: List[String]): Foo = new Foo(list.toArray[String])
```